# Diskpart batch file with user input selecting disk and partition number

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, diskpart

I am trying to creating batch file. How to use user input in selecting partition no? I want to format some partitions only using `diskpart`. I already learn how to select disk number but I want to learn select  partition number also. Sometimes partition number changed. So how can I user input for selecting partition number?

I am doing below now. But I want at time of selecting partition, it should ask me to select partition number also, but how?

```
@echo off

cd /d"%~dp0"
rem == List Disk and List Partitions ======================
echo >diskpart.txt List Disk
diskpart /s diskpart.txt

set /p Disk=Please enter the disk number:
if "%Disk%"=="" goto :eof
echo > diskpart.txt Select disk %disk%
echo >> diskpart.txt list partition
diskpart /s diskpart.txt

echo ============= Please check your Disk and all Partition numbers before continue =============

pause

rem == List Disk Again for Final Confirmation ======================
echo >diskpart.txt List Disk
diskpart /s diskpart.txt

set /p Disk=Please enter the disk number:
if "%Disk%"=="" goto :eof
echo > diskpart.txt Select disk %disk%

rem == 1. Format System partition ======================
echo >> diskpart.txt select partition 1
echo >> diskpart.txt format quick fs=fat32 label="System"

rem == 2. Format Windows partition ========================
echo >> diskpart.txt select partition 3
echo >> diskpart.txt format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"

rem == 3. Format Recovery tools partition ================
echo >> diskpart.txt select partition 4
echo >> diskpart.txt format quick fs=ntfs label="Recovery"

echo >> diskpart.txt list partition

diskpart /s diskpart.txt

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

(Since I'm a new to stackoverflow I cannot use comment for clarification.)

> at time of selecting partition, it should ask me to select partition
> Is the first "partition" is ment to be "disk" ?

As I understood you present the user the diskpart output of `list disk` and want him to select the disk AND the partition at the same time?

Fetch all availabel disks and keep them in a list an than call diskpart for each disk and do `list partition`. That way the user sees all disks with all their partitions and can enter disk and partition number at once.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set DiskList=
for /F "skip=9 tokens=1,2,*" %%A in ('^(echo.list disk^) ^| diskpart') do (
    set DiskList=!DiskList! %%B
)

for %%a in (%DiskList%) do (
    echo.
    echo.Disk %%a
    for /F "skip=12 delims=" %%A in ('^(echo.select disk %%a ^^^& echo.list partition ^) ^| diskpart') do (
        if /i not "%%A" == "DISKPART> " echo.    %%A
    )
)
```

Additionally you may keep track of alls disk and partition numbers like in %DiskList% and verify that the user input makes sense.

With this diskpart-for-loops you could also use `detail disk` and `detail volume` after the disk selection to use those informations for further verification.

Another way to select disk and partition at once is to use select `volume`. This requires the partition to have a drive letter assigned which does not apply to the "System" (boot) partition.

EDIT
You almost found the answer youself. You have already listed the disks and asked the user for a disk number. Do the same for the partition number. The only difference is that you need to select a disk before you can select a partition.

```
echo >diskpart.txt List Disk
diskpart /s diskpart.txt
set /p Disk=Please enter the disk number:

rem - listing partition needs a selected disk
echo >diskpart.txt select %Disk%
echo >diskpart.txt list partition
diskpart /s diskpart.txt
set /p Part=Please enter the partition number:

echo >diskpart.txt select %Disk%
echo >diskpart.txt select %Part%
rem - do whatever you want to do, e.g. like
echo >diskpart.txt format ... 
diskpart /s diskpart.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Above commands will give me only list of disks and partitions, i agree but i want batch file also ask me which partition number you want to format so that i can put my partition number like 1 or 2 or 3 for system,  windows, Recovery partitions format purpose...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can select the partition the same way like the disk. Except that you have to select a disk before you can select a partition. The plain diskpart commands would be "select disk 0", "select partition 1" "format ...."

Comment: your commands displaying list of disk and partitions. It's not asking me which disk and which partition you want to format. I don't want to put disk no and partition no in batch file. I want cmd commands will ask me for disk selection and partition selection.. like this " set /p Disk=Please enter the disk number:" . Actually i am not expert in cmd commands so i here for some person read my question and exactly make batch file as i need... In my above question i can put disk number but i don t know how to put partition number... i want like this  " Pls enter partition number "... Thanks